# Keras: How to obtain after an epoch the samples of the validation dataset with a wrong prediction?

Tags: validation, tensorflow, callback, keras

During training of my CNN with Keras, after each epoch I obtain the validation accuracy (val_acc). For instance I obtain val_acc: 0.9910 which means that the current trained model can predict, as expected, 991 out of 1000 samples of my validation dataset. Correct?

Then, **how can I know (via callback or maybe enabling somehow the level of verbosity) which are the 9 samples of my validation dataset that resulted with incorrect prediction?**

Comment: I found a workaround using pure tensorflow, using the "print_misclassified_test_images" parameter and now I get the information I was looking for, that I'm using to ensure the labels are correct for those particular images that result in a wrong prediction.